# Help with time series comparisons using periodograms

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, filter

I have a dataset consisting of time series signals of different lengths obtained from different groups of patients. I am trying to understand the commonalities of the time series of each group. Firstly, I am confused if I am supposed to filter my signals to get rid of any frequencies above the sampling frequency/2, and if so, which filter to use for this (sampling frequency=32Hz) - note my time series is somewhat noisy. Secondly, I wanted to look at the periodogram and the average power spectral density at each frequency within a group - but I am not sure if I understand the periodogram very well - if I have different time series lengths then my periodogram length will vary too, so I am not sure how this comparison can be made.

Being from Pure Math, I know Fourier analysis purely from the perspective of functions and using Fourier transforms to obtain the coefficients that describe the projection of these functions onto an orthonormal system. With periodograms however, I noticed that the x-axis represents sample frequencies. I am confused with the distinction between sampling frequencies vs. underlying frequencies of the generating function (say I have $sin(2\pi x)$ sampled at 10Hz, does the periodogram characterize the 1Hz underlying frequency of the function?)

Any resources on understanding how to analyze and remove noisy components of time signals from a machine learning perspective would be much appreciated! Due to time constraints, I have shied away from long textbooks on digital signal processing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: From your description, I guess your time sequence dataset is already discrete values after sampling with a sampling frequency of 32 Hz. Thus, your data sequence contains information from 0 Hz up to 16 Hz only, and nothing above 16 Hz you can/need to filter out. However, you may pass your data sequence through a low-pass or band-pass filter to get rid of the noise, which you do not need and below 16 Hz.

Comment: If you apply an N-point Fourier transform (FT) on a time sequence with sampling frequency 32 Hz, then the N-point output sequence of the FT covers the frequency range from -16 Hz to 16 Hz. For example, if N = 32, then the frequency sequence corresponding to FT result is [0, 1, 2, … 16, -15, -14, …, -2, -1] Hz. If you increase the FT size (i.e. the value of N), the covered frequency range is still the same, but the frequency resolution increases. For instance, if N = 64, then the frequency sequence becomes [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, … 16, -15.5, -15, …, -1, -0.5] Hz.

Comment: In case when your time sequence is of real numbers, the frequency response is symmetrical about 0 Hz. Thus, you only need to keep the positive frequency part of the FT result.